# Is it worth caching Python's range(start, stop, step)?

Tags: python

In a Python program which runs a `for` loop over a fixed `range` many times, e.g.,

```
while some_clause:
    for i in range(0, 1000)
        pass
    ...
```

does it make sense to cache `range`:

```
r = range(0, 1000)
while some_clause:
    for i in r
        pass
    ...
```

or will it not add much benefit?

Comment: If in doubt: benchmark.

Comment: @deceze I appreciate your opinion and doing benchmarks is always a good advice. But if you check answers, there is some story behind how `range` works and its differences in python 2 and 3. So I'd argue and say that this question makes sense.

Comment: Wait wait wait why are you doing for i in range (100)? How about just ensure $i$ is an integer and check 0<=i<99? Sorry if this is a stupid suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't, a `range` call does almost nothing. Only the `iter`ing part, which is not optional, has a cost.

Interestingly, caching makes it slower for some reason, in the example below.

My benchmarks:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("""
for i in range(10000):
    pass""",number=10000)
1.7728144999991855
>>> timeit.timeit("""
for i in r:
    pass""","r=range(10000)",number=10000)
1.80037959999936
```

And caching it breaks readability, as the Zen of Python states:

```
Readability counts.
```

and

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python `2.*`, `range` will return a `list`, and you should use`xrange`. 
`xrange` (2.*) or `range` (3.*) are `lazy evaluated`, which means it actually evaluated the next requested item when you ask for it.

So, no, no need to cache. Instantiate the range where you need it, 
no need for tricks and magic there, it's already implemented in Python.

Answer (score 0):

It won't benefit. If you want to enhance your loop activities refer to the comparison of : https://dev.to/duomly/loops-in-python-comparison-and-performance-4f2m

You can have an idea of how can improve things.